# Two-parameter Array Sort

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, parameters

I have a 14x14 array, with each element being binary-packed information that when unpacked will give me two parameters, A and B.  (Let's put the parameters in the form A:B for easier discussion here.)  Now, I need to sort the array such that A increases from top to bottom (column) and B increases from left to right (row).

I thought about sorting the rows by B, and then sorting the columns by A, but then I realized that won't work.  Say I sort the rows by B.  Then when I sort the columns by A, that could screw up the ordering of B.

Any ideas?

Comment: One of them is going to have to have priority. What's the correct layout for, e.g. `[[0:1 1:2 2:3 1:4]
[5:6 6:7 3:8 7:1]]`?

Comment: @JoshCaswell not necessarily

Comment: put it all in a 1 dimensional array and sort it

Comment: @aaronman - Being one dimensional vs two dimensional shouldn't affect the ability of the data to be sorted.

Comment: @JoshCaswell The correct arrangement is: [[0:1, 1:2, 2:3, 1:4] [7:1 5:6 6:7 3:8]].  Forgot to mention, this is in C (ugh), so I don't have any fancy pre-written functions to use for this.

Comment: @Aiias as long as you have any defined order that you can iterate through anything can be sorted, but I would imagine for this person it would be easier to put it in 1d first

Comment: @JohnCaswell: That will not guarantee sort order.

Comment: Can you explain step-by-step how you sorted @JoshCaswell's example by hand?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I ended up writing an answer, but it's not necessary to have a priority.  For example, take the elements (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1).  You don't need to know how to compare the second and third element yet can still put the four together in a 2x2 matrix satisfying the desired properties

Comment: It sounds like you're sorting by B, using A as a tie breaker.

Comment: Or sorting by A, using B as a tie-breaker.  It's not necessary to know in advance which has higher priority.

Comment: @JoshCaswell No, that will not work.  If I sort by A in the columns and then B in the rows, that could cause the columns to become unsorted again.

Comment: @bauer2010 see my answer.  If you sort all of the elements (as if you had a list and just sorted by the first element), you can lay out the elements in the matrix carefully so that sorting each row by B doesn't break the column sort

Comment: My point is that unless every A[i] has the same relationship to A[i-1] as does B[i] to B[i-1], you can't have both sorted at the same time.

Comment: @JoshCaswell As the question is currently stated, the desire is for a partial ordering, not for a total ordering

Comment: You're right, @Nirk, I was misunderstanding the goal here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort the entire list of 196 elements by A, then lay out the elements so that the first row contains the smallest 14 A, the next row contains the next smallest, etc.  In this way, every element from the `i`th row is smaller (according to A) than every element from the `j`th row if `i > j`.

Then, go row by row and sort by B.

As a small example, lets do a 3x3 case with pairs (9,1) (8,2) ... (1,9). The sort by A would yield (1,9) ... (9,1) which you lay out like this:

```
(1,9)  (2,8)  (3,7)
(4,6)  (5,5)  (6,4)
(7,3)  (8,2)  (9,1)
```

Then you sort each row by B.  Changing the order of the elements of B doesn't break the core assumption about A because every element in a given row are less than every element in higher rows (for example, the minimum A in the third row is 7 and the maximum A in the second row is 6).

Then you get:

```
(3,7)  (2,8)  (1,9)
(6,4)  (5,5)  (4,6)
(9,1)  (8,2)  (7,3)
```

EDIT: the question was clarified as follows:

> Ok, this is starting to make sense, but say I have this: [[-1 -1 2:8 -1 -1] [ -1 3:7 4:16 5:2 -1] [ 2:14 3:9 2:6 5:9 1:2] [ -1 9:8 4:2 9:1 -1] [-1 -1 2:2 -1 -1]]. "-1" represents a null value, thus should not be sorted. The final sorted array needs to remain in such a diamond shape.

To keep the "diamond shape", you merely fill out the matrix according to the pattern.  With the example:

```
[[-1 -1 2:8 -1 -1] [ -1 3:7 4:16 5:2 -1] [ 2:14 3:9 2:6 5:9 1:2] [ -1 9:8 4:2 9:1 -1] [-1 -1 2:2 -1 -1]]
```

First pull out the elements

```
[2:8 3:7 4:16 5:2 2:14 3:9 2:6 5:9 1:2 9:8 4:2 9:1 2:2]
```

Then sort by `A` (In this case, to break ties, we use the B value):

```
[1:2 2:2 2:6 2:8 2:14 3:7 3:9 4:2 4:16 5:2 5:9 9:1 9:8]
```

Then construct the rows we need.  If you look at the pattern, the number of elements in the rows are `1,3,5,3,1`, so the rows are

```
[[1:2] [2:2 2:6 2:8] [2:14 3:7 3:9 4:2 4:16] [5:2 5:9 9:1] [9:8]]
```

Now we sort the rows by `B` value:

```
[[1:2] [2:2 2:6 2:8] [4:2 3:7 3:9 2:14 4:16] [9:1 5:2 5:9] [9:8]]
```

Now we can rebuild the diamond:

```
[[-1   -1   1:2  -1     -1] 
 [-1   2:2  2:6  2:8    -1] 
 [4:2  3:7  3:9  2:14 4:16] 
 [-1   9:1  5:2  5:9    -1] 
 [-1   -1   9:8  -1     -1]]
```

Verify that the rows and columns are correctly sorted :)

Comment: Let me break your algorithm. Here's (data format: `(B, A)`)the data `[[(3, 2) (4, 3)][(5, 1)(6, 0)]]`. Try to sort it, see what happens. Sorting by B will break sorting by A.

Comment: so sorting by a yields the list `[(3, 2) (4, 3) (5, 1) (6, 0)]`, which you lay out as `[[(3, 2) (4, 3)][(5, 1) (6, 0)]]`.  Sorting each row by B yields `[[(3, 2) (4, 3)][(6, 0)(5, 1)]]`.  " A increases from top to bottom (column) and B increases from left to right (row)."  If you read the two columns' A values you get `[3,6]` and `[4,5]` (both satisfactory) and reading B values from rows gives you `[2,3]` and `[0,1]` (both satisfactory)

Comment: @SigTerm: I think you're having the same misunderstanding I was just having. The A values need to be sorted only in _columns_, B values in the rows. The second row just needs to be switched. Columns: 3 < 6, 4 < 5 Rows: 2 < 3, 0 < 1

Comment: @JoshCaswell: As far as I can tell, it is definitely possible to create set of data where sorting by columns will break row ordering.

Comment: That is a different question @bauer2010 :)  Nonetheless the same approach applies (sort by `A` using `B` as a tiebreaker, *laying out the cells starting with the first row in the pattern you want*, then *sorting the cells in each row*).  The invariant "every element from the ith row is smaller (according to A) than every element from the jth row if i > j." will still be preserved

Comment: Yeah, I think Nirk is right. When you sort by A, every element in every row is greater than or equal to every element in the preceding row, so the column ordering won't break however you go on to sort the rows.

Comment: Ok, this is starting to make sense, but say I have this:

[[-1   -1   2:8   -1   -1] [ -1   3:7  4:16  5:2  -1] [ 2:14 3:9  2:6   5:9  1:2] [ -1   9:8  4:2   9:1  -1] [-1   -1   2:2   -1   -1]].  

"-1" represents a null value, thus should not be sorted.  The final sorted array needs to remain in such a diamond shape.

Comment: @bauer2010 next time ask the entire question first :)  I'll edit my response to answer your new question "The final sorted array needs to remain in such a diamond shape"

Comment: `format->[columnKey:rowKey]`. Ideal order: `[x:y x+1:y][x:y+1 x+1:y+1]` Data that breaks algorithm.   `[1:1 2:0][100:0 101:1]->row sort->[1:1 2:0][100:0 101:1]->column sort->[100:0 2:0][0:1 101:1]`. Ordering in row 0 broken by column sort.

Comment: @SigTerm you didn't actually read my response.  You sort *all 4* elements as if they were a single list and then lay them out (read my response: "You can sort the entire list of 196 elements by A")

Comment: @SigTerm, you'd actually get: `[1:1 2:0][100:0 101:1]->row sort->[1:1 2:0][100:0 101:1]->column sort->[2:0 1:1][100:0 101:1]`

Comment: @Nirk: Also won't work, because if one element has higher priority and it's value increases in the middle of the row, it can break ordering within row.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: "Row vs column" depends on memory layout. Please see "ideal order" in original comment.

Comment: @SigTerm: I think your "ideal order" is addressing a question other than the one the OP asked, hence the confusion. There's no requirement in the original question for the ys in your second group to be higher than the ys in your first group. Either way, the result of your algorithm is not same same result as Nirk's algorithm would produce from the same data.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: "such that A increases from top to bottom (column) and B increases from left to right (row)."

Comment: @SigTerm: And that requirement is satisfied by this: `[1:1 2:0][100:0 101:1]->row sort->[1:1 2:0][100:0 101:1]->column sort->[2:0 1:1][100:0 101:1]`

Comment: @SigTerm lets say X is a 2x2 array.  The requirement is `x[0][0].A <= x[1][0].A, x[0][1].A <= x[1][1].A, x[0][0].B <= x[0][1].B, x[1][0].B <= x[1][1].B`

Comment: @Nirk: And as far as I can tell, this requirement cannot be reliably satisfied for all possible input datasets. You could try bruteforce, but that's it.